# Debugger for angulartics

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics-api

I am using `angulartics`(Google I analytics) for web analytics. When I am using `ga-debug`, it logs only for GA scripts.

For example `ga.create()`, I used:

```
"angulartics.setUserProperties('custdimension': 1)"
```

Is there a chrome extension available to test `angulartics`?

Comment: Are you using angulartics the plugin for angular http://angulartics.github.io or is it something else?